# Symfony 1.4 form security - change in input values by users wielding firebug

Tags: forms, security, symfony-1.4

If any user change input value through firebug or any other debugging tool. My form is performing process successfully with that id which is not available in my input.

For example, If a user is logged in to application with user id 1 and he is authorized to send messages to user 2 and 3 only. Now while composing the message, when he is selecting the user from the drop down, he changes the id with firebug to 4 (which is not authorized). But message simply goes to user 4. How should I handle it? Do symfony provies something form encryption or something else. So user can not modify this type of thing form any browser Add-on.

How can I secure my form in Symfony 1.4? Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always validate the user input. In symfony you can use validators (e.g. `sfValidatorChoice` or `sfValidatorDoctrineChoice`). Please [read the docs](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/10-Forms#chapter_10_sub_form_handling_with_data_validation).

Comment: or sfValidatorPropelChoice ;)